# Update a hash after searching an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes,

```
[
 {id: 1, tool_id: 1, user_ids: [1]},
 {id: 2, tool_id: 2, user_id: [2]},
]
```

I want to search through it and if there is a certain tool_id, I want to append a user_id to the list of user_ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
h = [
 {id: 1, tool_id: 1, user_ids: [1]},
 {id: 2, tool_id: 2, user_id: [2]},
]
```

Try

```
def add_user_id(h, tid, uid)
 el = h.find { |i| i[:tool_id] == tid }
 el[:user_id] << uid if el
end 

add_user_id(h, 2, 3)
p h
```

which outputs

> [{:id=>1, :tool_id=>1, :user_ids=>[1]}, {:id=>2, :tool_id=>2, :user_id=>[2, 3]}]

Comment: You can use `find { ... }` instead of `select { ... }.first`

Comment: @Stefan Nice, thanks.

Comment: I tried this, I was wondering if it was possible to actually update the array h rather than return another array

Comment: @TheGeorgeous It updates the array; it doesn't create another one. That's what `<<` does.

Comment: my bad, I was trying it on console

Answer (score 1):

Say the `user_id` you want to insert is `100` for `tool_id = 1`:

```
arr.each { |a| a[:user_ids] << 100 if a[:tool_id] == 1 }
#=> [{:id=>1, :tool_id=>1, :user_ids=>[1, 100]}, {:id=>2, :tool_id=>2, :user_id=>[2]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A short version using [`Enumerable#find()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find). (There is no handling for unknown `tool_id` values.)

```
# add the user_id 4 to the hash with the tool_id 2
arr.find { |e| e[:tool_id] == 2 }[:user_ids] << 4
```

Comment: if `find` method dont find any results, this code produce error. `NoMethodError: undefined method <<' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @LukasBaliak The second `=` is very important, thanks. That there is no handling of missed `tool_id` values is already mentioned in the answer, within the brackets.